# Disable download button until file download is finished (AngularJS 1.4)

Tags: angularjs

in AngularJS 1.4 app we need to disable download button until file download is finished and enable it afterwards. Ideally it should work eve in IE 7 :)

### Page

```html
<button ng-click="downloadFile()"
                            ng-class="inProgressDownloadFile ? 'btn-disabled' : 'btn-enabled'">
                        <img ng-show="inProgressDownloadFile" src="imgs/ajax-loader.gif"/>
                        <span>Download</span>
                    </button>
```

### Controller

```html
$scope.downloadFile = function() {
if ($scope.inProgressDownloadFile) {
                return;
            }
$scope.inProgressDownloadFile = true;
FileService.downloadFileById($scope.fileId).then(function(response) {
var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12"});
var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                    var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
                    downloadLink.attr('href',url.createObjectURL(blob));
                    downloadLink.attr('target','_self');
                    downloadLink.attr('download', 'invoice.xlsm');
                    downloadLink[0].click();
}
$scope.inProgressDownloadExcel = false;
               }, function(response) {
                    $scope.inProgressDownloadExcel = false;
               });
console.log('End of method downloadFile().');
        };
```

### Service

```html
factory.downloadFileById = function(fileId) {
            var httpConfig = {
                 responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                 headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/json',
                         'Accept': 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12'
                     }
            };

            return $http.get(restAppBaseContext + 'restFile/?id=' + fileId, null, httpConfig);
        };
```

### Problem

File is downloaded but corrupted! When I open downloaded excel file I get popup message: "We found a problem with some content in invoice.xlsm. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? ...". If I click "Yes" I get another popup message: "Excel cannot open the file invoice.xlsm because the file format or file extension is not valid. ...".

Comment: Well...when you have a question while you're developing that, feel free to come on back.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: SO is here to help you, not to code for you..

Comment: Added code. I ask only because I can't proceed further myself :(

Comment: Added problem description.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> ng-disabled

```
<button ng-click="downloadFile()"
                        ng-disabled="downloaded">
                    <img ng-show="inProgressDownloadFile" src="imgs/ajax-loader.gif"/>
                    <span>Download</span>
                </button>
```

Use `$scope.downloaded` as default `true` until download complete.

for more reference go to [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-disabled.asp)

Comment: This is just alternative to what I've already done and it won't solve problem that downloaded file is still corupted!

Comment: As you describe file is downloaded but corrupt so either problem in file not angular.

Comment: File is OK, it's not corrupted if I download it using $window.open() method. So the problem is how to download it not corrupted and in the same time be able to do some action once file download finished.